# How can I use my android GPS in my notebook through USB?

Tags: usb, gps, google-earth

How can I use my Android GPS in my notebook through USB? My notebook doesn't have bluetooth, and the wireless is not working.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to take a look at [ShareGPS](http://sharedroid.jillybunch.com/user.html):

> ShareGPS allows you to use your mobile's GPS just as you would an external one for your PC. It has the ability to send GPS status strings out over Bluetooth using virtual com ports and **over USB** using TCP ports. Then you can use your favorite mapping program such as Google Earth to display current GPS position and to produce tracks.

<sup>(emphasis is mine)</sup>

There is a [user's guide](http://sharedroid.jillybunch.com/user.html) available explaining how to set it up on a Linux or Windows system. If your notebook is a Mac, there's nothing said on that here.

There's also a thread over at the XDA developers about [Simultaneous WiFi-Direct and GPS-via-USB tethering](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=929450) which might be worth a look (even if it's only for the GPS-via-USB part for you). If you wonder what that might use for the GPS part -- umm, above mentioned *ShareGPS* it seems. So this might count as an additional how-to for that said solution.

Comment: nice solution, but ... you may notice it is  not marked as the answer, even if I believe it is working, but I guess average hackers canNOT follow the instructions, for your solution you need to understand adb commands and GPS servers/services, and at the end it only works with google earth ... and the really bad news is that I cannot find another way, I was hopping for a solution that makes android just like a GPS dongle and the entire windows 10 can use it like a phone use internal GPS :(